# What does "if echo $line | grep -F = &>/dev/null" do?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

I'm not sure what the following line does in a bash script:

```
if echo $line | grep -F = &>/dev/null
then
  ...
```

I know `&>/dev/null` is short for `>/dev/null 2>&1`, I'm not sure, however, what the `=` is for and I cannot find any explanation.

Comment: It checks is there `=` symbol in `line` variable

Comment: It could be (perhaps) more clearly written as `if [[ $line == *"="* ]]; then ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man grep`

```
-F, --fixed-strings
       Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
       newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
       POSIX.)
```

So it's just checking for the presence of `=` as a literal string in `$line`

Comment: Not _in `$line`_, in the output of `echo $line` which could be completely different. As `echo` and the slit+glob operator are used.

Answer (score 1):

It does:

```sh
case $line in 
(*=*) : this would be the then block
;; 
(*)   : maybe an else\?
;;
esac
```

...only not very well, or nearly as quickly.